# phonegap removes lines from config xml on build

Tags: xml, cordova

During the build step of my app my phonegap seems to remove certain parts from my platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

```
   <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
```

becomes

```
 <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
```

and i can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: what version of cordova are you using?

Comment: Do you see Camera, File and FileTransfer plugins listed when you do "cordova plugins list"